# How distant objects should communicate with each other?

Tags: c#, delphi, events, architecture

I have simple program to install packages on computer.
User select package in GUI by pressing button and then "Installer" run installing thread. When installation is finished "View" show succes or error text.

[image: Application Architecture]

How can I send information directly between "View" and "Installer?
Or I always have to use all intermediary objects like:
View>Controller>ThisComputer>Instaler
Instaler>ThisComputer>Controller>View